# CDI not working when Injecting in Generics class - Java

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jpa, cdi, jboss-weld

I'm having problems with CDI on tomcat. That's some relevant part of my code:

```
public class JPAUtil {
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit");

    @Produces @RequestScoped
    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }


    public void close(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
        em.close();
    }

}
```

My DAO Class:

```
public class DAO<T> implements Serializable{

    private final Class<T> classe;

    @Inject
    protected EntityManager em;

    public DAO(Class<T> classe) {
        this.classe = classe;
    }
}
```

and a child class:

```
public class UserDao extends DAO<User> implements Serializable{

    public UserDao() {
        super(User.class);
    }
}
```

Because of the Generics, I used a producer for the DAO class:

```
public class DAOFactory {

    @Produces
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public DAO createDAO(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) injectionPoint.getType();
        Class classe = (Class) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return new DAO(classe);
    }
}
```

In this example:

```
public class Test {
    @Inject UserDAO userDAO;
    @Inject DAO<User> dao;
}
```

When I try to use the UserDAO class, everything works fine, but when I use the DAO, the EntityManager remains null. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `DAOFactory` you instantiate the DAO with `new` operator, if you do so, CDI has no chance to inject dependencies in the DAO instance. 
While in `UserDAO` CDI manages the entity manager injection.
So in `DAOFactory` you should set manually the entity manager in the newly created DAO instance.

Comment: OK, passed the EntityManager to the factory and set it on the DAO. This way it works, thanks!

Comment: @Montolide: please could you publish the corrected code in a 'SOLUTION' section at the end of the question?